# How to split a body of text at an empty line in java?

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I have multiple paragraphs in a body of text. I would like to create a String array that would store each paragraph as an element. So at each empty line, i wish to split.

The paragraphs I'm parsing is server log data, each paragraph is a new file so i wish to store each files server log data as an element in an array.

```
String[] fileFSCK = text.split("\\n\\n")
```

That is my current code, and it result in no split being performed, so basically fileFSCK[0] is all the of the text file.

Comment: What exactly stops you?

Comment: Please explain your query with an example

Comment: I have added some code, hopefully it can help explain my problem.

Comment: Could your files have \r\n endings?  (ie. Windows-style)

Comment: Try `String[] fileFSCK = text.split("\\R{2}")`

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, Your suggestion worked.

Comment: System. Get property ( " line. Separator " )

Comment: I typed it in mobile spare me for case

Comment: Sorry, @WiktorStribiżew but using that code only removes lines, it does not seem to split the paragraphs into elements. Any ideas?

Comment: What Java version is it? Try `split("(?:\r\n?|\n){2}")`